# Windows Authentication - allowed users in database instead of web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I am writing an MVC 5 web app with Windows Authentication.

I do not want to store the list of users in the web.config file, such as:

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="user1, user2"/>
    <deny users=”?”/>
</authorization>
```

I want to store the users (user1, user2) in a database table.

What do I need to do to make sure the users in the table are authorized and all other users are denied in the web app?

I have researched and it's possible to do this in Core using AuthorizationPolicyBuilder, but I'm looking for a solution for MVC 5.